# How to execute aspx file using windows task scheduler

Tags: asp.net, windows, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to execute aspx file using windows task scheduler without using a console app?

Can it be done using bat script or maybe there is a way to do this in Task Scheduler directly?

Thanks!

Comment: The .aspx file is within IIS? You're wanting to request a URL from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Just open a browser exe file firefox passing the url as a parameter

```
c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBS file like below

```
    Dim iex
    Set iex = CreateObject("internetexplorer.app  location")
    iex.Navigate "http://www.yoursiteorlocalhost.com/yourpage.aspx?q=1"
    ie.Visible=True
```

Then schedule the file for execution or use [this](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on 'Scheduled Tasks' in Plesk
2. Click on 'Add New Task'
3. Enter a description and notification email if required
4. In the 'Path to executable file' field, enter the following path: C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe
5. In the 'Arguments' field enter the following: D:\vhosts\mysite.co.nz\httpdocs\schedule.vbs  (replacing mysite.co.nz with your domain name)
6. Because cscript.exe won't execute an asp file, we'll need to create a vbs script, that will then call the asp script. In the schedule.vbs script, we'll use the xmlhttp request to open a web page. Copy and paste the script below and save to a file called schedule.vbs and upload this to your site.

Call RunIt()
Sub RunIt()

Dim RequestObj
Dim URL
Set RequestObj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

'Request URL...
URL = "http://www.mydomain.co.nz/myScript.aspx"

'Open request and pass the URL
RequestObj.open "POST", URL , false

'Send Request
RequestObj.Send

'cleanup
Set RequestObj = Nothing
End Sub
7. Now you can create your myscript.aspx page, or whatever you would like to name it to perform the tasks you require to be scheduled.

Comment: code formatting and bullets doesn't work nicely with each other: in a list, the code block needs 8 leading spaces to be formatted, please edit :-)